# Where do we report sites copying SE content?

Tags: support

In a Google search today, I came across a site completely ripping off the SharePoint SE

```
http://www.techques.com/question/19-23308/Creating-a-Site-collection-programmatically-throws-exception--nativehr-0x80070005--nativehr
```

It's a direct rip off of this question:

[Creating a Site collection programmatically throws exception <nativehr>0x80070005</nativehr>](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/23308/creating-a-site-collection-programmatically-throws-exception-nativehr0x8007000/23310)

I filed a Google Spam report, and blocked their domain in my browser using the "Personal Blocklist (by Google)" Chrome extension

Is there somewhere I can report this to SE? Maybe their API key can be pulled?

Comment: Unlinked it - we don't really want to be giving them Google juice ;)

Comment: Well, everything is attributed... Sort of.  Every post and every comment links back to the original author on Sharepoint Stack Exchange, although the post itself doesn't link back to the original.

Comment: @Undo isn't that what `rel="nofollow"` is supposed to prevent?

Comment: @3ventic Ideally... but we should be safe. It still gives *some* Google juice.